# PHP exec with grep using a variable passed?

Tags: php, variables, grep, exec

I am sure there is an easy answer , but i searched and could not find.

I am basically trying to pass a variable to exec grep into a file

so

```
exec("snmpget -v 2c -c public $host $oid_model | cut -d':' -f4 | sed -e 's/^[ ]*//'", $model);
exec("grep $model /home/user/test.txt  |  cut -d':' -f1 | sed -e 's/^[ ]*//'", $new_model);
```

when printing my $model i get the output, when trying $new_model it does not.

Comment: I hope $model isn't something dynamically generated or user-provided, otherwise you've got a MASSIVE security hole and are likely to get your server completely DESTROYED by the first person to pass in `; rm -rf /` as the value for $model.

Comment: no theres no secret behind it. $model is created with the output from snmpget

Answer (score 1):

Try to quote the matching pattern in grep command:

```
exec("grep '".$model[0]."' /home/user/test.txt  |  cut -d':' -f1 | sed -e 's/^[ ]*//'", $new_model);
```

Comment: Wont work either, i tried " and '. i also saw some posts using "\$variable" that doesnt work either.  i tried '".$model."'

Comment: i did an echo gettype($model); says array. i am pretty sure i cannot get a result from exec grep b/c of this right? hmm. how to fix.

Comment: Ok thats the reason. Can you dump the value of `$model` using `var_dump($model);` and tell me the output.

Comment: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) ""model123""

Comment: its a small hack, but i did $new_model=$model[0];   that seems to work when i passed it onto grep. what do you think?

Comment: Actually that should be fine since anyway there is only 1 element in the array.

Comment: well that went down hill. now that i have a " in my output of model i wanted to get rid of it using sed. now i get a T_Variable error. heres the new line                                                        exec("snmpget -v 2c -c public $host $oid_model | cut -d')' -f2 | sed -e 's/"//' | sed -e 's/^[ ]*//'"", $model);
$new_model=$model[0];

Comment: and if i try to do a var_dump($model); it will still say T_Variable Error. I know for a fact its the sed removing the ". i removed that and placed it with another character and it works. how could i go around this?

Comment: Run `var_dump($model);` before tihs exec call and print the output in your question.

Comment: Sorry to bring this back up. got it all working just fine. but i got into a small issue where i am trying to grep for the exact string. yes i searched and used -w BUT heres the issues. If i have ABC, and ABC/ in my file. and i am searching for ABC (later i might need ABC/) it brings back both when using grep -w .how can i go around this?

Comment: @anunbhava if u can help :)